# Is this the simplest use case for an ElemMatch filter?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have the following unit test. It passes.

```
        [Fact]
        public async Task MatchFilter_FindsMatch()
        {
            var collection = GetCollection();   // This call returns an IMongoCollection<BsonDocument>. 
            var property = RandomStrings.LettersOnly();    // some random string with letters like "ghzlppa" or whatever.
            var innerArray = new BsonArray(new int[] { 2 });
            var innerDocument = new BsonDocument(property, innerArray);
            var cSharpList = new List<BsonDocument> { innerDocument };
            var array = new BsonArray(cSharpList);
            var wrapperDocument = new BsonDocument("child", array);
            await collection.InsertOneAsync(wrapperDocument);
            var subfilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq(property, 2);
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.ElemMatch("child", subfilter);
            var foundDocument = await collection.FindSingleAsync(filter);
            var deeplyNested = foundDocument["child"][0][property][0];
            Assert.Equal(2, deeplyNested.AsInt32);
        }
```

What I find strange is just how deeply one has to go in the deeplyNested call, and similarly in the setup, where one builds a document four layers deep. I'm wondering if there is a way to use the ElemMatch filter that doesn't involve drilling down four levels.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, the document looks like:

```
{child: [
          {property: [ 2 ]}
        ]
}
```

Finding a document with `2` in the array doesn't require the use of elemMatch, you can use:

```
Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("child.property", 2);
```

Comment: My purpose is to understand elemMatch.